# Override spring data jpa auditing @LastModifiedBy

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA Auditing and it's working. The problem is when I set a custom value in the property, this value is not persisted and I still have the auditing value.

**CustomAuditorAwareConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class CustomAuditorAwareConfig implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {
        return Optional.of("ANONYMOUS");
    }
}
```

**Entity**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(chain = true)
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {

    @id
    private String id;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastUpdateBy;

}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AvailableShipmentDatesDefaultService implements AvailableShipmentDatesService {

    private final MyRepository repository;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    @Override
    public void patchEntity(String id) {

        BaseEntity entity = 

        entity.setLastUpdateBy("Toto");

        repository.save(entity);
    }
}
```

The persisted value for lastUpdateBy is "ANONYMOUS"

Expect to have "Toto" instead of "ANONYMOUS"

Comment: Your expectations are wrong. The `@LastUpdatedBy` (and friends) are updated always by an entity listener regardless of what you set.

Comment: So it's not possible to update lastUpdateBy with another value?

Comment: Not manually. That is the whole point of those annotations/fields that they are updated automatically.